# a href not concatenating (nodejs, ejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have some trouble with some buttons that don't go to the correct route. I have an overview of items with a details button. When I click on it the route becomes

(localhost)/items/:itemname

inside this item I have another button that allows to add new data to this specific item. The link is supposed to be:

(localhost)/items/:itemname/data/newdata

but for some reason, when I click the button, it goes to

(localhost)/items/data/newdata

I tried several things, including putting the itemname in the href, until I suddenly got this route:

(localhost)/items/:itemname/:itemname/data/newdata

this is my current a href in the itemDetails.ejs file

```
<a href="data/newdata" type="button" class="(bootstrap stuff)">
```

When I'm at
(localhost)/items/:itemname/
it goes to 
(localhost)/items/data/newdata

could it be a problem with my gulp file? or my view engine?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use relative URLs.  If you just make the URL be `<a href="/items/data/newdata" type="button" class="(bootstrap stuff)">`, then it wouldn't be sensitive to what the URL of the current page is at all.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. When I went from the index page to the details page I needed a trailing slash. Since it was missing the add data button didn't add to the route.